# Macros in JavaScript or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, macros

Are there elegant methods for simulating user behavior (clicks, inputs) using JavaScript or PHP? I'm envisaging something along the lines of:

1. Enter something into a text box.
2. Click on the submit button
3. Click on a link that shows up on the following page (the location I
   can predict, but not the URL itself)
4. Aggregate the page results
   and return to me.

It somehow screams iFrame to me, but are there other ways? Also, the content would be an external website, so iFrame cross-scripting would raise errors.

Comment: It depends on how you want it to be seen/presented. If you are not bothered about seeing it happen, you could probably accomplish this entirely using PHP's CURL.

Comment: Can you tell cURL to "click" on something that is returned by another cURL request?

Comment: You shouldn't need to really. Curl the page with the form and submit it - then you get the content of the next page back, scan it for the link (as you say you know where it'll be), and then curl that link.

Comment: @Rio if you can strip the href out of the first response, it's just a matter of sending the second request to that URL.

Comment: Ajax call and only return the information you require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). It's being developed to do automated tests on websites and can certenly do the task you described.

You can also export the tests as PHPUnit test.